When I try to move the arm of my rig why is the movement so sensitive?
When I press G and attempt to move my rigs left arm bone the movement becomes uncontrollable and extreme. What am I doing wrong or perhaps this unexpected behaviour is caused by my Apple Magic Mouse 2?
Link showing the issue: https://i.ibb.co/Bj8tgKf/ezgif-7-3da995b8bf.gif

hello please share the armature. Have you unparented the controller?

@moonboots How would I check if the controller is unparented?

you can go into the Bone panel or simply unparent with Alt P or parent it to your root bone

@moonboots The parent box is greyed out so it won't let me parent it to the root bone or unparent it. See image in OP.

If there is a way to remove the parent from this bone then I'm quite sure it will fix the problem.

Found the solution at: https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/utnhe4/bone_parenting_menu_is_greyed_out_when_i_try_to/
Solution gave in the first reply. Excuse their name.

not sure to understand but ok   ;)
